# Floating point differences depending on how debug build is run

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, floating-point, testdriven.net

I am using a debug build and obtaining different results on the same machine whether I run under the debugger or not. I am using the excellent TestDriven.Net to run the unit tests.

- "run" with TestDriven.Net or the external NUnit runner produces the same result
- "run with debugger" with TestDriven.Net produces different results

The code is

- A complex iterative mesh deformation routine involving significant computation at the limits of floating point precision
- C#, VS2012 targeting .Net 3.5.
- Single threaded
- Only debug build, no release version has been built
- Same machine, no powersaving\speedstep or other feature I am aware of
- Vanilla C# - No unsafe code, unmanaged libraries, platform invoke etc.
- No debugger checks in code or strange third-party libraries

I have not tracked back to the first difference (tricky without a debugger!) but given how iterative the code is, its input sensitive and the tiniest difference will grow to significant proportions given enough time.

I am aware of how fragile fp reproducibility is across compilers, platforms and architectures but disappointed to find the debugger is one of the factors to throw this off.

Do I have just have to accept this as a fact of life or is there any advice you can offer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Do I have just have to accept this as a fact of life or is there any advice you can offer?

You have to accept it as a fact of life. Floating point code can be optimized differently in different situations. In particular, in some cases the JIT compiler can use a representation with *more precision/accuracy* (e.g. 80-bit floating point) for operations. The situations under which the JIT compiler will do this will depend on the architecture, optimization settings etc. There can be any number of subtleties about what you do with a variable (and whether it's a local variable or not) which can affect this. Running under a debugger affects JIT optimization settings very significantly in general - not just for floating point - so I'm not at all surprised by this.

If you perform floating point comparisons with a certain tolerance, it should be fine - it's very rarely a good idea to do *exact* equality comparisons on floating point types anyway. Of course it's possible that you're actually performing a non-equality comparison where the differences become significant, but I've rarely come across that as a problem.

Comment: Thanks Jon. The domain is computational geometry and the code involved is cleaning out degenerate cases co-linearities, coincidence etc. Its all tolerance based but the quantity and iterative nature eventually makes minor differences significant.

Comment: Is there no way to make the entire platform (JIT, debugger, …) use the SSE2 instructions when the computations involve single- and double-precision? The problem of floating-point reproducibility is considered solved in C, of all languages, thanks to these instructions.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: It's not just which instructions to use. Consider a local `double` variable - that could be stored in an 80 bit register, so when there are repeated operations, you can end up with a different value to if it were stored in normal memory as 64 bits. Removing that ability would be possible (as Java does with strictfp) but at the cost of optimization.

Comment: SSE2 instructions have their own 16 “XMM” registers they can use to store exactly a float or exactly a double. Even if a pre-existing ABI requires the old FP stack to be used, as long as the computations are made with the SSE2 instructions exclusively, those old registers, when they are used to pass arguments according to the ABI, only ever contain representable `double`s that are converted back without loss when read.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Right, I see. Unfortunately I don't have any inside information to know why these aren't used in the CLR. Presumably those instructions aren't universal across architectures though? Bear in mind that the CLR runs on ARM as well - does ARM have anything similar?

Comment: Old ARM processors have no FPU at all! But when they do they typically have single- and double-precision: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Floating-point_.28VFP.29 . One remaining sore point is not something missing but something that comes in addition to IEEE 754's basic operations +, -, *, /, sqrt: it is a Fused-Multiply-Add instruction that does not behave exactly like `*` followed by `+`, but that compiler may use as if it did, in the quest for speed, when the source code uses `*` and `+`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Right - so this likely wouldn't be an issue in ARM anyway, as it presumably wouldn't be using the same optimizations that it does in x86/x64.