# (How) does debugging change the workflow of the program?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Consider the following simple program:

```
var dblMax = Double.MaxValue;

var result = (dblMax * 1000) / 1800;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

When I build this in Debug mode and run (Ctrl+F5) or debug (F5) it, it prints `9.987140856842E+307`.

When I switch to Release mode and run (Ctrl+F5) it, it prints `8` for infinity.

I understand that this difference is due to some compiler optimization which is done in Release mode.

However, if I debug (F5) the *same build* in Release mode, it prints  `9.987140856842E+307` again!

How does the fact that I am debugging change the result of the calculation?

Edit:

I do not ask why debug mode and release mode yield different results. I wonder why release mode is yielding different results depending on whether I debug (F5) or not (Ctrl+F5).

Comment: The execution is *not* changed, at least not in the way you think. What is the result of `dblMax * 1000` (∞) ? What do you get if you divide ∞ by 1800?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not surprised by the infinite result. I am only surprised that the same build prints a different result depending on if I debug it or not.

Comment: would you be surprised if I said I can't reproduce this yet?

Comment: Indeed, I would be surprised (assuming that you have tried to). I ran exactly this code in a new c# console application in VS 2010 Professional.

Comment: I suggest you upgrade to a *supported* version of .NET. The earliest supported version is 4.5.2. VS 2010 came with 4.0 and couldn't be upgraded to a higher version. 4.5+ is a binary replacement for 4.0 so you won't be able to find people that can reproduce this *or* be affected by this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I am using VS2013, .net 4.6.1 and i can reproduce the problem...

Comment: @daniell89 I can't, in LinqPad, VS 2017 and .NET Core, VS 2017 and 4.6.1/2 debug

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I use VS2010 on a Windows 10 machine. So I guess I have a supported version of .NET

Comment: @wkl not exactly - VS 2010 can only run up to 4.0. Your code will run targeting 4.0 and certain features will behave differently. In any case, the debugger is part of VS 2010, a very old version. Do you have the same issue with 2015? The Community edition for both 2015 and 2017 is free and more powerfull than 2010 Pro, if not Enterprise

Comment: Got it with 2015! Even targetting 4.6.2. One more reason to upgrade to 2017 I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When debugging the JITter behaves different.

For one thing, local variables will in many cases have their lifetimes changed in order to be inspectable. Consider hitting a breakpoint after a variable was used during a calculation. If the JITter knows the variable is not going to be used after the expression, and it didn't prolong the lifetime of the variable, you could end up not being able to look at that variable, which is a core feature of debugging.

The JITer has a very clear knowledge about when a variable is useful to still have lying around. If during that time a register is available it might end up using this register to store the variable in.

However, with the debugger attached it might decide to instead use a memory location because the lifetime changed enough so that a register isn't available for that part of the code.

Floating point registers of the CPU have higher precision than the corresponding floating point storage formats, which means that once you either lift a value out of a register and into memory, or simply store it in memory the whole time, you will experience lower precision.

The difference between RELEASE and DEBUG build can end up dictating these things, as can the presence of a debugger.

Additionally, there can be differences between the different .NET runtime versions which can affect this.

---

Writing floating point code correctly requires intimate knowledge about what you are attempting to do and how the various parts of the machine and platform will interfere. I would try to avoid writing code like this.

Answer (score 3):

That is strictly related to the floating point precision. In debug mode, the compiler uses 80-bit precision. In release mode the compiler uses 64-bit truncated results.

When this is going to happen or not, depends on several configuration, settings and environment variables. For example, you can turno off optimizations on your configurations for release mode. That should help.

Take a look at this Jon Skeet answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18417944/637840

Comment: But why does the Release build have a different output when started with F5 or Ctrl F5?

Comment: This is a different matter - the multiplication should have resulted in infinity no matter what happens after that. It's impossible to reproduce though unless one finds a computer *without* .NET 4.5 installed. The OP though uses VS 2010 and either .NET 2.0 or 4.0 - these are very, very old versions

Comment: @wkl CTRL F5 will run the application without the debugger. F5 will debug on release mode.

Comment: @NicoRiff exactly. So both run on release mode. But still they produce different output.

Comment: @wkl that's not what NicoRiff said. F5 starts the debugger, even if the application was built in Release mode. That can change how an application runs. The debugger will install hooks etc anyway. `Ctrl + F5` though just starts the executable without any intervention

Comment: BTW, I was finally able to reproduce this in VS2015 with the latest updates, targeting 4.5.2 and 4.6.2. So this was fixed in VS 2017

Comment: The debugger will artificially prolong the lifetime of local variables to ensure you can inspect them at various points, this can change the storage location of a value from a register (which has higher precision) into a memory location (which has lower precision).

Comment: Thank you @LasseV.Karlsen . This seems to be the answer I was looking for. If you want to make your comment an answer, I would be happy to accept it (while of course still upvoting this helpful answer).